# Camel pattern for multiple sources specific messages aggregation and redirect to destination

Tags: java, apache-camel, eip

I have one problem, and don't know how to solve it using camel. I searched for related EIP in camel documentation, but without results.

Now I have simple route:

```
<route id="routeId">
    <from uri="Source1"/>
    <from uri="Source2"/>
    <to   uri="Destination"/>
</route>
```

Both sources sends JMS messages to Destination and at some point when Source finish its job it send specific end message, with some flag. What I need to do is to collect or count those end messages and send single end message to destination when I receive end messages from both sources. Only when i receive two end messages (imagine that its just simple message with some header flag) then i should send single one to destination.

Sorry if problem explanation isn't clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the Camel [aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html) and [filter](http://camel.apache.org/message-filter.html) patterns can be used for this scenario...

- use a filter to detect "end" messages and route them through an aggregator
- use a custom aggregation strategy to build up the single end message with a count
- use a custom completion predicate to trigger the completion message

something like this...

```
from("source1").to("direct:aggregateRoute"); 
from("source2").to("direct:aggregateRoute"); 
from("direct:aggregateRoute")
    .filter(header("isEndMessage").isEqualTo("true"))
        .aggregate(constant(true), new MyAggregationStrategy())
        .completionPredicate(new MyCompletionStrategy())
    .to("destination");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to pick from multiple inputs and does not want to perform any modification on the incoming message, 
you can do something like this:

```
from("URI1", "URI2", "URI3").to("DestinationUri");
```

for more info check this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples-multipleinputs) it helped me

Comment: I cannot find a from() method which takes multiple URIs. Do you know which version of Camel did this work for you ?

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-core-engine/latest/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html#from-java.lang.String-